# TLS errors in pod logs in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I use Kubernetes version 1.15.3 .
I use calico as cni plugin.

I have a deployment that has service configured to as Nodeport on a port serviced by HTTPS protocol.

For some reason when I look at one of the pods of the deployment I see this output:

```
2020-01-07T08:45:02.905Z [INFO]  http: TLS handshake error from 10.233.92.0:60286: tls:first record does not look like a TLS handshake
2020-01-07T08:44:42.884Z [INFO]  http: TLS handshake error from 10.82.83.213:45654: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

The IP 10.82.83.213 is the IP of the node and the second IP is some internal IP of Kubernetes.

These errors are not interfering with the actual work of hte pod since it is up but I makes it hard to look for pother errors since this lines appears every 4 seconds.

Initially I tried removing the Probes but that did not help.

Once I remove the NodePort service or changes the label these error stops but ofcourse then the pod is not reachable.

Does any one knows the root cause for this?
I would assume kube-proxy but I couldn't find evidence of that.

thanks

Comment: Have you set the liveness probes etc to use `https` scheme?

Comment: Yes I did. I even removed them completely afterwards and still it persists in the logs.

Comment: Could you share your config in YAML format? Also could you provide some details about your env (which cloud, minikube or kubeadm, etc).

Comment: Which config do you mean? It is provisioned with Kubespray which means actually kubeadm based.

Comment: Yaml file of nodeport service